# How to create something where dropping different views on a view causes different actions in Android

Tags: java, android

To clarify my question, basically there's a textView (called topText) with a draglistener,
a bottomButton with a setOnTouchListener that creates dragging.

Right now when I drop bottomButton onto the textView it does the action I've specified in ACTION_DROP.

I want to create another button (button2) where when it gets dragged and dropped to the texView it runs something different to what happens when I dragged bottomButton to the textView.

How can I do this? I plan to have mutilple different views that get's dragged into the textView (topText) and each activates its own specific code.

I havecode for just the buttonButton and topText like:

```
//DRAG LISTENER
        topText.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                        // Executed after startDrag() is called.

                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        // Executed after the Drag Shadow enters the drop area
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
                        Log.i("dragged","DRAGGED");
                        //CODE TO RUN SOMETHING
                    }

                    //WHERE CODE GOES   //ACTION WHEN THING IS DROPPED/ENDED
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
                        return (true);
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        bottomButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("bottomButton", "bottomButton");
                //CREATES AFTER SHADOWY AFTERIMAGE OF BUTTON
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(bottomButton);
                v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: so use two different `ClipData` and pass them to `View#startDragAndDrop` method when starting dragging those two buttons

Comment: So I'm trying to wrap from switch to break with a if statement right? How do I get the clipdata in the if statement? I'm tring to do something like this if (data.equals("bottomButton").  How do I use the clipdata directly and pass that into my if statement from the bottomButton.setOnTouchListener? I'm wrapping the if statement around the switch of the setOnDragListener.

Comment: you have `DragEvent` passed to `onDrag`, dont you?